# Rails schema not updating for a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema, migration

I have a development env and a beta env for the app that I am building. Yesterday I came across a strange error.

I wrote a migration to change one of the tables and it worked fine on my dev env. Once I deployed the changes to the beta env it ran and but when I access the page it started giving me trouble. The new columns that I added were all undefined columns when it comes to the beta environment. So looked at the schema for the column on the beta side using column_names function on the class and it still had the old columns while logging into mysql there and checking the fields in the table shows me the new ones.

Anyone have any idea why is the schema not updating while the database was updated. Is there anyway to update the schema for a class, like some function or something.

Comment: Are you using the same database for both environments?

Comment: Nope. Both are diff databases with the same schema. One is on my computer at work and the other is on our dedicated VM at godaddy.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the only solution I've found is to rename the table.